# Give a big-O estimate of $(x+1)\mathrm{log}(x^2+1) + 3x^2$

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

I wanted to know if the following solution demonstrates that the function $f(x) = (x+1)\mathrm{log}\, (x^2+1) + 3x^2 \in O(x^2)$, because my answer and the book's answer deviate slightly.

Clearly,

$$3x^2 \in O(x^2) \tag{1}$$
$$x+1 \in O(x)\tag{2}$$

The following inequality is where the book and I differ, but I understand how the author obtained his big-O estimate. I said

$$\mathrm{log}(x^2+1) \in O(\mathrm{log}(x^2+1))\tag{3}$$

Therefore, the product of $(2)$ and $(3)$ renders

$$(x+1)\mathrm{log}(x^2+1) \in O(x \mathrm{log}(x^2+1)) \tag{3}$$

Finally, $(1)$ and $(3)$ gives us this big-O estimate

$$(x+1)\mathrm{log}(x^2+1) \in O(\mathrm{max}(x^2,x\mathrm{log}(x^2+1)) = O(x^2) \tag{4}$$

Any problems! Thanks!

Comment: It's "obvious" to me (especially after looking at a couple of graphs on a graphing calculator) that $\log(x^2 + 1) < x$ for all $x > 0$, but I don't know whether that's enough proof for your purposes. I'm also puzzled why you introduced the symbol $n$ in place of $1$.

Comment: @DavidK Substituting $n$ for 1 was a mistake. And yes, it is clear that $\mathrm{log}(x^2+1) \in O(x)$, but I put $O(\mathrm{log}(x^2+1)$ instead, because that came to me first.

Comment: Do you mean as $x \to 0$ or $x \to \infty$?

Comment: I think you meant to write ${}+3x^2$ on the left of $(4)$, but aside from that it looks OK now. As noted in the answer by marty cohen, you could simplify the $O(\log x)$ factor a bit, but in the end all you need is for that part to be $O(x)$. Let me guess, the book went directly to $O(x)$ for that part rather than waiting until line $(4)$, was that the difference in their approach?

Comment: Actually, the book has $\mathrm{log}(x^2+1) \in O(\mathrm{log}(x))$ in substitution for my $(3)$. Is it more natural to adopt a slower function as the author does when dealing with big-O estimates, because that's the only reason I can think of for the author not using $\mathrm{log}(x^2+1) \in O(\mathrm{log}(x^2+1))$.

Answer (score 1):

If this is as
$x \to \infty$,
then
$\log(x^k+a)
=O(\log(x))
$
for any fixed $k$
and $a$.

Also,
$\log(x)
=O(x^c)
$
for
any $c > 0$.

This should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The issue from what I see is the in the $(x+1)\mathrm{log}(x^2+1)$ portion of your proof. Here, you didn't properly derive the Big-O value to it's tightest bound. I'll give you a headstart on the problem and then I'll leave the rest for you.

Within $\mathrm{log}(x^2+1)$ you can note that $x^2 + 1 \leq 2x^2$ whenever $x \gt  1$. This is because if $x \gt  1$ then $x^2 \gt  1$, so we would just substitute $x^2$ for $1$ to obtain $x^2 + 1 \leq 2x^2$. Now, given this information you can $\mathrm{log}$ both sides and find the correct value, which should be $O(x\mathrm{log}x)$.

In general, it is always better to have your Big-O and Big-Omega notation as tight as possible so that you can most accurately determine the growth rate.

Hope this helps.